# How do I capture and redirect files ending in .cfm in web.config minus index.cfm?

Tags: regex, web-config

I have a site with a homepage at index.cfm. The page content is included based on a URL parameter, so example.com/about (which is rewritten in the web.config file to index.cfm?p=about) will include about.cfm. I want to keep people from accessing files such as about.cfm directly, ideally permanently redirecting them to /about, but I obviously need to allow access to index.cfm since not excluding it from the rule results in infinite redirects.

The rule I created (which should also theoretically allow access to files in the /ajax/ directory) is:

```
<rule name="don't allow direct access to .cfm pages" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.+[^\/ajax\/]\/)?([^\/]+[^index]).cfm$" />
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

[According to the tester at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/f5JLmJ/1), this should not select 1, 2, and 4 in the list below (as desired), selects 3 (as desired), but captures the entirety of index.cfm?p=contact in 5, which I suspect is the problem:

1. http://example.com/contact
2. http://example.com/index.cfm?p=contact
3. http://example.com/contact.cfm
4. http://example.com/ajax/contact-form.cfm
5. http://example.com/index.cfm?p=contact.cfm

If I visit example.com/contact.cfm it gets redirected to https://example.com/index.cfm?p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=index&p=contact, even if it's the only rule in the file, but following is the code to prettify the URL anyway:

```
<rule name="Prettify URL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.+\/)?([^\/]+)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}index.cfm?p={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```xml
<rule name="don't allow direct access to .cfm pages" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(?!ajax)(?!index\.cfm)(.*?).cfm.*$" />
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="index.cfm?p={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This rule should redirect request to any `.cfm` page (except `index.cfm` and those in `ajax` folder if any) to desired URL.

Here regex `^(?!ajax)(?!index\.cfm)(.*?).cfm.*$` is used. It uses negative lookaheads to prevent matching anything starting with `ajax` or `index.cfm`.

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HS3fHe/1).

> Where am I going wrong?

I'm not sure on correctness of your `web.config`, but your regex was very wrong. `[^index]` means non of the letters `i`, `n`, `d`, `e`, `x`, for example. I recommend read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) to grasp some understanding in regexes.